# Mockito: How to match any enum parameter

Tags: java, enums, mockito

I have this method declared like this

`private Long doThings(MyEnum enum, Long otherParam);`
and this enum

```
public enum MyEnum{
  VAL_A,
  VAL_B,
  VAL_C
}
```

Question: How do I mock `doThings()` calls?
I cannot match any `MyEnum`.

The following doesn't work:

```
Mockito.when(object.doThings(Matchers.any(), Matchers.anyLong()))
        .thenReturn(123L);
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`Matchers.any(Class)` will do the trick:

```
Mockito.when(object.doThings(Matchers.any(MyEnum.class), Matchers.anyLong()))
    .thenReturn(123L);
```

`null` will be excluded with `Matchers.any(Class)`. If you want to include `null` you must use the more generic `Matchers.any()`.

As a side note: consider using `Mockito` static imports:

```
import static org.mockito.Matchers.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
```

Mocking gets a lot shorter:

```
when(object.doThings(any(MyEnum.class), anyLong())).thenReturn(123L);
```

Comment: Adding static imports is far better one :)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the above solution try this...

```
when(object.doThings((MyEnum)anyObject(), anyLong()).thenReturn(123L);
```