# Specify specific enum being passed into method in Mockito doReturn method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a junit test in which I have an object mocked within a class. Let's call the class `Mocker` with the @Mock of MyManager called `mocker`.

Example class:

```
public class Mocker {
   private MyManager myManager;

   public void myMethod() {
       String x = "test";
       final String result1 =  this.myManager.execute(dummyEnum.ENUM_A, x);
       final String result2 =  this.myManager.execute(dummyEnum.ENUM_B, x);

       if(result1 == true) {
           //Do something
       }
       if(result2 == true) {
           //Do something else
       }
   }

   public enum dummyEnum {
        ENUM_A,ENUM_B
   }
}
```

My current junit test uses the following: `doReturn(null).when(mocker).execute(any(dummyEnum.class), anyObject());`

However, this will return null for both result1 & result2. **How can I specify that when execute() is executed with ENUM_A it returns a String of `Hello` and execute() with ENUM_B returns a String of `Goodbye`**

I have seen the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19949762/mockito-how-to-match-any-enum-parameter) but I don't want to just say any instance of that class, I want to specify a certain enum from that class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `eq()` methods (which stands for equals) of the Matchers class.

```
Mockito.doReturn("Hello").when(mock).execute(Matchers.eq(dummyEnum.ENUM_A), anyObject());

Mockito.doReturn("Goodbye").when(mock).execute(Matchers.eq(dummyEnum.ENUM_B), anyObject());
```

Answer (score 3):

> I have seen the answer here but I don't want to just say any instance
>   of that class, I want to specify a certain enum from that class.

In your case just pass the enum instance :

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
...
Mockito.doReturn(null).when(mocker).execute(eq(DummyEnum.ENUM_A), any());
Mockito.doReturn(null).when(mocker).execute(eq(DummyEnum.ENUM_B), any());
```

Note 1 : `any()` should be used only as you don't have the choice or that the value doesn't matter (which is rarely the case).

Note 2: avoid `Matchers` class. Use `ArgumentMatchers` instead.
From Mockito 2, this class is deprecated in order to avoid a name clash with `Hamcrest org.hamcrest.Matchers` class and javadoc also states this class will likely be removed in version 3.0.